# oAuth + ADFS Federation; Is this possible, and how would one go about doing it in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, oauth, asp.net-membership, wif, adfs

I'd like to support multiple authentication mechanisms such as oAuth and ADFS in my MVC site.  Is this possible, and how would I go about using one or the other?

My understanding is that ADFS/WIF will hook into the entire site preventing alternates such as oAuth

Comment: ADFS is not strictly an "authentication mecahanisms". It is an STS capabale of issuing SAML tokens using WS-Federation, SAMLP and WS-Trust.

Answer (score 1):

FedUtil only allows an application to point to one instance of ADFS. If you use it again to point to another instance, it simply overwrites the old ADFS info. in the web.config.

The trick is to federate ADFS with another STS which does support the OAuth protocol.

[StarterSTS](http://startersts.codeplex.com/) is an example of an STS which supports OpenId. This was developed by [Dominick Baier](http://www.leastprivilege.com/). He has just announced via his blog that he is developing a MVC version.

Matias Woloski has blogged about a protocol bridge [here](http://blogs.southworks.net/mwoloski/2010/07/12/consumer-identities-for-business-transactions/). It supports not only OpenID but also OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

@nzpcmad suggestion of adding an STS to do protocol translation is correct. Another alternative is to use ACS (AppFabric Access Control Service).

You can alternatively add the trusts relationship on the web.config manually (or run Fedutil on a separate project and merge the changes). In this case the trust would be to an STS that knows how to deal with OAuth and SAML/WS-Federation (like the STSs mentioned by @nzpcmad). Out of the box, WIF only understands SAML tokens and WS-Federation/WS-Trust.

Comment: Interesting idea - merging two web.config. How far could the merge go? Which parts could you merge? e.g. If there were two STS configured, which one would it choose?

Comment: @Euginio I'm looking at your latest ACS drop on Codeplex.  Neat stuff!  Link for those interested: http://claimsid.codeplex.com/releases/view/62929

Comment: Thanks! Let us know if we can improve anything please.

Answer (score 0):

StarterSTS does not support OAuth but the follow-on project by the same guy does. Check out http://identityserver.codeplex.com/ for more details.

In addition to supporting OAuth it is new code using the ASP.NET MVC framework and WCF for its underpinnings.

This is only at CTP 1 status and is not yet considered a full release yet so review carefully.